# How to make .gitignore safe? (sensitive directory threats in web-based application)

Tags: git, security, web, github

We know that .gitignore can be accessed via a web browser, for example accessing www.yourwebsite.com/.gitignore. 
Therefore, my .gitignore files viewable, and we can see some directory of our web.

For example:
This is my .gitignore file:

```
my_application/cache/*
public_html/money/my_bank/account/etc/my_PIN.txt
```

I don't want other people find my account directory. how git do that?
And I always use .gitignore files any time.

Comment: Don't put sensitive information in a publicly accessible folder.

Comment: Why would you upload your `.gitignore` file to your website in the first place? Your website should be separate from your source control and only include distributable files.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not be storing sensitive information inside your repository root, as it's prone to accidentally committing it.

However, you can put `.gitignore`s places other than the root.  If you create `.gitignore` in `public_html/money/my_bank/account/` with the contents `*`, git will ignore everything from that directory down - *including* the `.gitignore`.  This way, you don't have to commit it.